# Resume an Autolaunched Flow with Wait

Tags: flow, visual-workflow

I am having issues with an `Autolaunched Flow` that is kicked off via `Process Builder` whenever a `Task` is added or edited. There is a `Wait` element that waits a few seconds then should proceed to lookup the `WhoCount` on the record and update a custom field on the `Task` based on that value.

Whenever the flow is kicked off, it gets stuck in the `Paused` and `Waiting Interviews` and never resumes as it should. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have a pause in the first place?

Comment: My company gives different "credit" to sales people for different activity types and the number of contacts on the activity record, so the flow pauses for 15 seconds so that the task record has time to save and subsequently update the WhoCount field to properly calculate sales credit. So technically, it isn't paused...it gets stuck in the wait element

Comment: Can you show your flow? what event is the wait waiting for? show your Wait event details?